# $broadcast gets called multiple times on ng repeat, even if called once from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast

Controller
onSuccess

```
function onSuccess(data) {
                        vm.myData = true;
                        $scope.$broadcast('showGood',{index});
                    }
```

Directive

```
function myDir($document) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {

                index: '=',

            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.showGood = function(){
                  scope.selectedIndex = scope.index;
                  //DOM Manipulation
                  scope.$apply();
                };
                scope.$on('showGood',function(event, data){
                  console.log("event triggered - showGood" + data.index); // ---> Getting called as many no of times as ng repeat elem
                  event.preventDefualt();
                  event.stopPropagation();
                  if(data.index === scope.index) {
                    scope.showGood();
                  }

                });
```

html -

```
ng-repeat - div and a button with ng-click ->

 <div my-dir index="$index" ng-click = "onSuccess()" class="btn-div" title="Click">
```

$broadcast gets called multiple times. How to prevent it? Writing destroy, doesn't do trick of $apply for DOM manipulation now.

Thanks

Comment: What gets called multiple times? The event listener (`scope.$on()`) or the broadcaster (`$scope.$broadcast('showGood',{index});`)? Btw. you have an syntax error near `event.preventDefualt();` in your code.

Comment: It will listen to event multiple times because your directive will get created nth time due to ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening you are using your directive inside ng-repeat and subscribe to `showGood`  nth time due to ng-repeat

Solution is append index something like

**Controller**

```
           function onSuccess(index,data) {
                        vm.myData = true;
                        $scope.$broadcast('showGood'+index,{index});
                    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div my-dir index="$index" ng-click = "onSuccess($index)" class="btn-div" title="Click">
```

**Directive**

```
function myDir($document) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {

                index: '=',

            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.showGood = function(){
                  scope.selectedIndex = scope.index;
                  //DOM Manipulation
                  scope.$apply();
                };
                scope.$on('showGood'+scope.index,function(event, data){
                  console.log("event triggered - showGood" + data.index); // ---> Getting called as many no of times as ng repeat elem
                  event.preventDefualt();
                  event.stopPropagation();
                  if(data.index === scope.index) {
                    scope.showGood();
                  }

                });
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z0tvdyg8/)

Comment: This works, but one issue I see is scope.apply() is not running or DOM manipulation does not execute for the first time. If I run it again, it works!

Comment: Do I need a timeout

Comment: yes as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38401610/5621827) you can give it a try

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do can you create a fiddle for the problem.